# Front-end (HTML) is not fetching data in spring boot app from mysql database in Microsoft Azure

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven, azure

I am trying to fetch data from MySQL database which is hosted in Microsoft Azure and my spring boot maven app is also deployed in Azure.

When I am hitting my data hosting link, it displays data in JSON format on a web browser. For Example - https://xyz.azurewebsites.net/checklist displays data in JSON format.

On the other end When I am hitting my front-end link, it displays my design. For Example - https://xyz.azurewebsites.net/search.html displays HTML view.

Note - This complete app working fine on local server //localhost/3306. But it is not running fine when I am deploying it on Microsoft Azure. Kind of mismatch issue.

Where am I doing a mistake?

**Hierarchy**

```
 |-Project
   |-src/main/java
     |-Controller
     |-DAO
     |-Entity
     |-Main
     |-Repository
     |-Service
     |-src/main/resources
     |-Static
        |- Search.html
        |- Index.html
     |-application.properties
```

**Pom.xml**

```
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>CheckListMavenWebThree</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<!-- <parent> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> 
    <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version> </parent> -->
<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-
boot-starter-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-envers -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-envers</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-envers -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/main/test</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <!-- <resource> <directory>src/main/webapp</directory> <excludes> <exclude>**/*.java</exclude> 
            </excludes> </resource> -->
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>

            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Controller.java** (able to fetch data on host(Azure))

```
package com.example.Controller;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;

import com.example.Entity.Checklist;
import com.example.Service.CheckListService;

@Controller
public class CheckListController {
@Autowired
private CheckListService checkListService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/checklist" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Object index() {
    return checkListService.findAll();
}
```

**App.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [ 'ngResource' ]);
app.controller('CheckListController', [
    '$scope',
    '$resource',
    function($scope, $resource) {
        function fetchAllCheckList() {
            $scope.CheckList = 
$resource('http://localhost:8080/CheckListMavenWebThree/checklist')
                    .query(function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $scope.Message = data;
                        return data;
                    });
        };

        fetchAllCheckList();
        $scope.refresh = function() {
            fetchAllCheckList();
            console.log(fetchAllCheckList());
        };
```

**Search.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>CheckList</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/right-panel.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" onload="javascript:closeNav()">
<div ng-controller="CheckListController" id="main">

<div >

        <span style="font-size: 23px; cursor: pointer"     onclick="openNav()">&#9776;
            Search</span>
    </div>


    <form name="checkListForm" id="main">

        <table border="2" >


            <tr>
                <th>Site_Name</th>
                <th>WSC_Serial_Number</th>
                <th>CheckList_01</th>
                <th>CheckList_02</th>
                <th>CheckList_03</th>
                <th>CheckList_04</th>
                <th>CheckList_05</th>
                <th>CheckList_06</th>
                <th>CheckList_07</th>
                <th>CheckList_08</th>
                <th>CheckList_09</th>
                <th>CheckList_10</th>
                <th>CheckList_11</th>
                <th>CheckList_12</th>
                <th>CheckList_13</th>
                <th>CheckList_14</th>
                <th>Notes</th>
                <th>Completed_By</th>
                <th>Setup_Tech</th>
                <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
            <div><label style="font-size:18px; font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;">Search: <input ng-model="search.$"></label><br><br>
            <tr ng-repeat="row in CheckList  | filter:search:strict">
                <td><span ng-bind="row.site_Name"></span></td>
                <td><span ng-bind="row.wsc_Serial_Number"></span></td>
                <td><span ng-bind="row.checkList_01"></span></td>
                <td><span ng-bind="row.checkList_02"></span></td>
                <td><span ng-bind="row.checkList_03"></span></td>
                <td><span ng-bind="row.checkList_04"></span></td>
                <td><span ng-bind="row.checkList_05"></span></td>
                <td><span ng-bind="row.checkList_06"></span></td>
                <td><span ng-bind="row.checkList_07"></span></td>
                <td><span ng-bind="row.checkList_08"></span></td>
                <td><span ng-bind="row.checkList_09"></span></td>
                <td><span ng-bind="row.checkList_10"></span></td>
                <td><span ng-bind="row.checkList_11"></span></td>
                <td><span ng-bind="row.checkList_12"></span></td>
                <td><span ng-bind="row.checkList_13"></span></td>
                <td><span ng-bind="row.checkList_14"></span></td>
                <td><span ng-bind="row.notes"></span></td>
                <td><span ng-bind="row.completed_By"></span></td>
                <td><span ng-bind="row.setup_Tech"></span></td>
                <td><span ng-bind="row.date"></span></td>
                <td>
            </tr>
        </div>
        </table>

        <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" onmouseover="openNav()"
            onmouseleave="closeNav()">
            <!--  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a> -->

            <a href="search.html">&nbsp;&#9906;&nbsp;&nbsp;Search</a> <a
                href="createnew.html">&#169;&nbsp;&nbsp;Create</a> <a href="update.html">&#9851;&nbsp;&nbsp;Update</a>
            <a href="delete.html">&#9762;&nbsp;&nbsp;Delete</a>
            <a href="earth.html">&#9762;&nbsp;&nbsp;Earth</a>
        </div>

        <span><button type="button" data-ng-click="refresh()" id="refresh">Refresh</button></span>
</div>
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'  src="./js/rightpanel.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'  src="./js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'  src="./js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/app.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/theme-default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/theme-blue.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" 
modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
<httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
    arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -
Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\gs-spring-
boot-0.1.0.jar&quot;">
</httpPlatform>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Application.properties** (I am naive so I just learned and tried to implement. Is application.properties is correct? It allow me to connect mysql with azure from local host also)

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/static/js/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://*****.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/*****?    verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username:*******@*******server
spring.datasource.password:*******
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver


# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy =     org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen     database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =     org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL:debug

#naming convention according to me
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-    strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

What stuff Am I doing wrong? Is that hosting link issue?

Comment: Would you please post your app's web.config file in KUDU? btw,the page you offered is not found.

Comment: I have changed that page name. But here is the link http://smartrain.azurewebsites.net/search.html http://smartrain.azurewebsites.net/checklist. I am also editing my post with web.xml. Thank you for your help and let me know if you need to know anything. Please help me out to sole this issue.

Comment: Did you use the runable jar package and web.config file to run your application on azure? Is the jar package's name in web.config file matches the jar package you deployed to azure?

Comment: @JayGong I am uploading it on azure directly from spring tool suite by right clicking on project and publish as an azure app. Is web.config file is same asweb.xml? I do not have any web.config file in my project.I think I used runnable jar package I am not sure what exactly that means.

Comment: If you used the tool deployed it directly, please make sure you  chosed your project matching JDK and Tomcat container version in the portal application settings. try to change deployment way and use FTP to deploy the war package to the D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps\ directory.

Comment: Hi,keval0001,Any progress?

Comment: @JayGong Sorry for a late reply, I was working on other stuff. I tried that but still not working for me. I will try it today and will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @JayGong Error->  **Mixed Content** The page at 'https://smartrain.azurewebsites.net/search.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://localhost:8080/CheckListMavenWebThree/checklist' ** This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.**   Can you help me out how to solve this issue? I remember solving this issue before but I haven't got any appropriate solutions.

Comment: You could refer to this thread 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33507566/mixed-content-blocked-when-running-an-http-ajax-operation-in-an-https-page' to try to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, your project works fine locally, so consider the issue of deployment.

You could followed the [official tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-spring-boot-web-app-on-azure) to deploy `spring-boot` project to azure.

Combining the steps in the [official tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-spring-boot-web-app-on-azure) and your actual situation, I provide the following check points:

***Point 1:*** Please use `mvn package` to bulid the JAR package in the directory under which the `pom.xml` file is located.

[image]]

***Point 2:*** Please make sure that the jar package name configured in web.config is the same as the uploaded jar package name.

[image]

**Point 3:** Please use FTP to publish `jar files` and `web.config` to `D:\home\site\wwwroot\` directory on KUDU.

***Point 4:*** Please make sure `ApplicationSettings` matches your project such as `jdk version`,`tomcat version`.

[image]

If you want to deploy a `war` file, you need to configure the ApplicationSettings of your app service on Azure portal, then upload the war file into the path `D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps`.

As references, please refer to the documents and threads below.

1.[Configure web apps in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#application-configuration-examples)

2.[Create a Java web app in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-java)

3.[Deploying Springboot to Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103878/deploying-springboot-to-azure-app-service).

Hope it helps you.