# Azure-deployment of WAR-file shows blank page

Tags: java, maven, azure

I'm developing a simple web app that i need to deploy to Azure as an App Service.

It's a Spring Boot project and i've followed the instructions from this website: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/spring-framework/deploy-spring-boot-java-app-with-maven-plugin

I've done few changes, like adding some configuration to `pom.xml` so that the right subscription is chosen. When i run `mvn azure-webapp:deploy` it completes without errors and i see a bunch of stuff is uploaded. But when i visit my site at the given url `xxx.azurewebsites.net` all i get is a `Error 404`. I even tried the Azure Toolkit for Intellij, it completes successfully but site still gives error.

I've watched hours of youtube videos and lots of tutorials on this and i can't see that i've missed any steps.

Comment: Hi, any progress now? Does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 1):

Combining the steps in the [official tutorials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-spring-boot-web-app-on-azure) and my deployment procedure, I provide the following check points for you:

***Point 1:*** Please use `mvn package` to bulid the JAR package in the directory under which the `pom.xml` file is located.

[image]]

***Point 2:*** Please make sure that the jar package name configured in web.config is the same as the uploaded jar package name.

[image]

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
        arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\<your project name>&quot;">
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Point 3:** Please use FTP to publish `jar files` and `web.config` to `D:\home\site\wwwroot\` directory on KUDU.

***Point 4:*** Please make sure `ApplicationSettings` matches your project such as `jdk version`,`tomcat version`.

[image]

If you want to deploy a `war` file, you need to configure the ApplicationSettings of your app service on Azure portal, then upload the war file into the path `D:\home\site\wwwroot\webapps`.

In addition, you could check the log files on KUDU : `https://<your project name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole.`

As references, please refer to the documents and threads below.

1.[Configure web apps in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#application-configuration-examples)

2.[Create a Java web app in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-java)

3.[Deploying Springboot to Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103878/deploying-springboot-to-azure-app-service).

Hope it helps you.