# Azure uploaded jar but doesn't run it (Spring boot)

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've got myself an Azure Web App Service and a SQL database to go with it. I'm using Azures Intellij plugin to "Run On Web App". Issue is, it doesn't run anything, however it does put the jar in the folder:

```
Connecting to FTP server...
Uploading artifact to: /site/wwwroot/ROOT.jar ...
Uploading successfully...
Start Web App...
Logging out of FTP server...
Deploy successfully!
```

I then, using console try to run the `ROOT.jar` by using `java -jar ROOT.jar`, but I get the error message

> Java is not recognised as an internal command or external command

In the webapp application settings I have `Java Version: Java 8` So I'd assume it'd give me the ability to run java, but this has just made me question the way I'm doing it. Am I deploying the app wrong?

Comment: You should share what platform you are on. And then fix your command line so the appropriate `java` executable is on your PATH or %path% (or you use the absolute path to the executable). This really has nothing to do with Azure or Spring. The command line is telling you it can't find an executable called "java".

Comment: Yeah I know the error message has nothing to do with spring or azure,  but I mean the fact that this is how it's deploying could possibly indicate that I'm deploying it wrong? As in, shouldn't it run out of the box without me having to run the jar @jdb

Comment: plus I'm unsure how to set the path through commandline @jdv

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you are doing. If you are using an Intellij plugin, stay in the UI and use the plugin gestures the plugin gives you. Even opening up a shell in the IDE won't necessarily have any Java since Intellij bundles its own Java runtime for running Java based gestures. e.g.: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/intellij-deploy-java-web-apps-to-azure/

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to deploy as a WAR, even if it's Spring Boot to get this to work as an Azure Web App.

Comment: Did you mean you run the jar in the Kudu cmd, if yes,you could not run jar there.And what did you mean "it doesn't run anything", did it show nothing when you went to browse the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your SpringBoot project lacked a `web.config` file which will be deployed at the path `wwwroot` for helping to handle your `ROOT.jar`.

Here is a sample `web.config` file for SpringBoot runnable jar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
        arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\ROOT.jar&quot;">
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

As above, it comes from my answer of a similar SO thread [Deploying Springboot to Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103878/deploying-springboot-to-azure-app-service) which you can refer to.